# java profile tool without gui

Tags: java, jvm, profile

Is there a java profile tool that works without a GUI in Linux, just like `top`? I don't have the permission to use tools like jprofile and jvisualvm to work in remote model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html You can query heap and cpu details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HPROF](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html).

```
Command used: javac -J-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples Hello.java

CPU SAMPLES BEGIN (total = 126) Fri Oct 22 12:12:14 2004
rank   self  accum   count trace method
   1 53.17% 53.17%      67 300027 java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry
   2 17.46% 70.63%      22 300135 java.util.zip.ZipFile.getNextEntry
   3  5.56% 76.19%       7 300111 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2
   4  3.97% 80.16%       5 300140 java.io.UnixFileSystem.list
   5  2.38% 82.54%       3 300149 java.lang.Shutdown.halt0
   6  1.59% 84.13%       2 300136 java.util.zip.ZipEntry.initFields
   7  1.59% 85.71%       2 300138 java.lang.String.substring
   8  1.59% 87.30%       2 300026 java.util.zip.ZipFile.open
   9  0.79% 88.10%       1 300118 com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ErrorType.<init>
  10  0.79% 88.89%       1 300134 java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen
```